# gnuplot in c++ - path error

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I'm trying to implement the code below from this site:

https://sites.google.com/site/bettereaclone/introduction/gnuplot/c-example-gnuplot-1

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gnuplot_i.hpp"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        Gnuplot g1("lines");
        cout << "*** plotting slopes" << endl;
        g1.set_title("Slopes\\nNew Line");

        cout << "y = x" << endl;
        g1.plot_slope(1.0,0.0,"y=x");

        cout << "y = 2*x" << endl;
        g1.plot_slope(2.0,0.0,"y=2x");

        cout << "y = -x" << endl;
        g1.plot_slope(-1.0,0.0,"y=-x");
        g1.unset_title();
    }
    catch (GnuplotException ge)
    {
        cout << ge.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I installed the gnuplot (http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html)

*gnuplot_i.hpp* file (https://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/source/browse/trunk/gnuplot_i.hpp)

When I run this code, I get this problem:

[image]

The error:

> 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I've no idea why. thanks!!

Comment: You are redirecting to a piece of code. I suggest you to isolate your problem to a reproducible code snippet. SO is not a code review forum.

Comment: Let me try to fix this.. Cause I really don't know how to post it.. But I'll fix

Comment: thats true, is the samething! Is there a way to close this post? I flagged this question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like path to gnuplot is malformed, not in quotation marks or simply not read properly.

Try forcing the path by uncommenting this line and correcting it to point gnuplot directory on your machine:

```
// Gnuplot::set_GNUPlotPath("C:/program files/gnuplot/bin/");
```

Comment: I tried it before the 'try' and nothing changed :(

Comment: You can also try to take path in quotation marks: `Gnuplot::set_GNUPlotPath("\"C:/program files/gnuplot/bin/\"");`

Comment: Same error...
I tried too to substitute the _C:/Program Files_ by _C:\Proga~1_ and didn't work.

Comment: My last idea is to reinstall gnuplot to a directory without space in path.

Comment: I can try it, but I'm gonna wait a little more and try other things.